# can linux ip stack handle non standard protocols?

Tags: ip

can linux ip stack handle non standard protocols? i.e protocol field has values 143-252.

Linux build: Yocto Project - Poky

Comment: If you have any particular uncommon protocol in mind, it would be better to mention it and/or its characteristics.

Comment: Due to some limitations, I'd like to discard UDP header and would like to have only the data (which comes in some specific format).

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw sockets for this. See [raw(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html). With raw sockets you send and receive non-standard transport level protocol data in IP packets instead of TCP, UDP, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of raw sockets. However, don't know if there is some limitation in the linux build I've specified.

Comment: @user1977050 If you have IP, you have raw IP sockets.